# Returning Column Index/Value Based on Max value of Specific row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Sorry if I have completely butchered the terminology in the title. Relatively new to Excel.

I have the following table.

| Name | Score A | Score B | Score C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 10 | 8 | 6 |
| Sue | 9 | 12 | 10 |
| Joe | 11 | 2 | 4 |
| Susan | 7 | 9 | 10 |
| Tim | 10 | 12 | 4 |
| Ellie | 9 | 8 | 7 |

What I am trying to achieve is that for each person, to return the score type for that person's best score. I'm referencing the person's name on another sheet.

For example. For `Susan`;

Their best score is `10` and that is under `Score C`.

So I want the final value in the `Score Type` column in my other sheet for `Susan` to be `Score C`

Like so

| Name | Best Score | Score Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ellie | 9 | Score A |
| Bob | 10 | Score A |
| Susan | 10 | Score C |

I know to get the index of each persons row by

```
=MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A, 0)
```

I can get the max value for that person via

```
{=MAX(IF($A$2:A = A2,($B$2:$D)))}
```

I'm just not sure how to use that information to return the column label corresponding to the person and their max score.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is pretty easier. Try-

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(MAX(B2:D2),B2:D2,0))
```

[image]

For dynamic spill array-

```
=BYROW(B2:D7,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(B1:D1,x=MAX(x))))
```

[image]

> EDIT: Then try below formula-

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,1,MAX(($A$2:$A$7=$I3)*($B$2:$D$7=$J3)*(COLUMN($B$2:$D$7)))-COLUMN($A$2))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I may have oversimplified my question as I'm actually getting the data from another sheet. I have updated my question to reflect this. I don't think the `B2:D2` would work if like in my updated question Ellie is now the first name, it would then be referencing Bob's score instead

Comment: Then try `=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,1,MAX(($A$2:$A$7=$I3)*($B$2:$D$7=$J3)*(COLUMN($B$2:$D$7)))-COLUMN($A$2))`.

Answer (score 1):

For Larger Data you could use this one

[image: Index Match]